# Contacts from SIM card are not visible on MIUI

Tags: contacts, miui

How I can I display contacts from SIM card on my new Android phone? (Xiaomi with MUIU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings

==> System apps

==> Contacts

==> Display Preferences

==> Enable "Show SIM contacts"

[image]